# Finding the value of $xy+xz+6yz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If $x^2-2y=-13, y^2-4z= 14$, and $z^2+6x=-15$ then find the value of $xy+xz+6yz$.

Which way should I proceed. I did try to simplify the expressions but it was of no use. Please help.

Comment: I solved your problem. Here is your hint. Complete $x^2 + 6x$ to a perfect square.

Comment: But there is no such expression in the question and neither was I able to derive the expression. How did you reach it?

Comment: Then here is your second hint :) If you add all three equations side by side, you get the term $x^2+6x$ and similar almost-quadratic terms with $y$ and $z$. You complete each of them to squares. Then, you will see how to find the values of $x,y,z$.

Comment: I get it... Let me try! Thanks!

Comment: Is this a trick question? Because I can't find any real numbers that satisfy the three equations

Comment: Do you require $x,y,z$ to be real? If so, the solution is fairly easy. If you allow complex values, then it is significantly more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

After summing our equations we obtain:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+6x-2y-4z+14=0$$ or
$$(x+3)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Only if $x,y,z$ are required to be real.

Comment: @almagest Yes, you are right. :) It means that they are reals.